# Showing work for Gcd

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have these two pairs I'm supposed to find the GCD of as a linear combination: $(33,44)$ and $(101,203)$.  Now, I have the answers but I have a professor that is a real fricken stickler about showing work.  I want to know from what I wrote down is if I've shown as much as I can.

For the first, I have:
$44=33+11$ and
$33=3\cdot11$

$11=(-1)\cdot33+44$ and
$11=-33+44$

For the second:
$203=2\cdot101+1$

$1=(-2)\cdot101+203$
$1=-202+203$

Answer (score 1):

Since you're supposed to express the gcds as  linear combinations, it would be best to leave them as $$11=-1\cdot 33+44\\1=-2\cdot101+203$$
Still, it looks good.

Comment: Got it, gracias!

Answer (score 1):

If your teacher is strict about showing work, try this method, based on the Euclidian algorithm for calculating gcd (used on the pair $(22, 13)$ since your two pairs do not give many steps to illustrate):
$$
9 = 22 + (-1)\cdot 13\\
4 = 13 - 9 = 13 - (22 + (-1)\cdot 13) =(-1)\cdot 22 + 2\cdot 13\\
1 = 13 - 3\cdot 4 = 13 - 3\cdot((-1)\cdot 22 + 2\cdot 13) = 3\cdot 22 + (-5)\cdot 13
$$
The strategy is to construct smaller numbers as linear combinations of $13$ and $22$, then use any of the numbers for which you've already made a linear combination to make even smaller numbers. After a finite number (usually quite small, like $3$ here) of steps, you're going to reach the gcd.

There is no "correct" path to follow here, as long as you work toward smaller numbers (some ways might be slightly slower than others, though). I could just as well have written $4$ as $22 - 2\cdot 9$, and worked from there. More notably, though, I could've written $1$ as $9 - 2\cdot 4$, using neither $13$ nor $22$ directly. A potential optimization of my choices above might be to write $4 = 2\cdot 13 + (-1)\cdot 22$ directly, and then go for $1 = 13 + (-3)\cdot 4$, making it two steps instead of 3.

You have a lot of choice in how to reach gcd, but if you keep it all straight, you *will* end up with a correct linear combination in the end, and you will have some work to show for it.